# Check if wildcard covers given path in powershell

Tags: powershell, path, wildcards

I'm trying to figure out how to test in PowerShell if a wildcard in command-line notation would be triggered for a given path. To be clear I have something like this:

```
For ($exception in $Exceptions) {
    For ($path in $ListOfAllItems) {
        If (IsPartOfPath -Wildcard $exception -Path $path) {
            -- do something....
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is how to implement this `IsPartOfPath` function. I have tried simple `$path -imatch $wildcard` but didn't like the outcome, since it falls into full RegEx syntax. Is there a fancy way in PS to do it other than writing all wildcard check by yourself?

The idea to solve it I had was to get a resource path to which `$path` refers and check if `$exception` refers to the same resource. However I have no idea if it is possible in PowerShell :/

Answer (score 0):

The `-like` operator is probably what you're after. It doesn't do any regex comparison, and it works with `*` and `?` exactly as you expect. It's case insensitive.

Unfortunately, it does have a couple extra features: `#` matches a number and square-bracketed arrangements like `[abc]` match any one of the characters inside the brackets. It seems to have all the same semantics as `Get-ChildItem`'s filter and VB.NET's [`Like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator.

If those are problematic, you can escape the undesired wildcard characters before using `-like`:

```
$path -like ($wildcard.Replace('[', '[[]').Replace('#', '[#]'))
```